# Minimum of two properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph that looks like [this](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=9w2wi9)

a-[:LIKES { frequency:6 }]->ice
b-[:LIKES { frequency:3 }]->pizza etc

I am running this query, to find out common foods two people like. It works fine if I total the frequency attribute to create a like-index for food.

```
START b=node:node_auto_index(name='B') 
MATCH p = b-[r1:LIKES]->stuff, someone_else_too -[r2:LIKES]->stuff 
WITH b, someone_else_too, r1.frequency + r2.frequency AS likeIndex 
RETURN likeIndex ,someone_else_too 
ORDER BY likeIndex DESC
```

However, what I'd like to do is find minimum of the two frequency value (NOT minimum of the total). So something like this min(r1.frequency, r2.frequency). The goal is to weed out skewness that would increase the like ranking if one in the pair had really high affinity to a particular food.

```
    START b=node:node_auto_index(name='B') 
    MATCH p = b-[r1:LIKES]->stuff, someone_else_too -[r2:LIKES]->stuff 
    WITH b, someone_else_too, min(r1.frequency,r2.frequency) AS likeIndex 
    RETURN likeIndex ,someone_else_too 
    ORDER BY likeIndex DESC
```

However, Cypher won't accept that syntax. Any suggestions or work around? See Neo4j console [here](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=9w2wi9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.0 you can use `case/when`: http://console.neo4j.org/r/y8sqi1

```
START b=node:node_auto_index(name='B') 
MATCH p = b-[r1:LIKES]->stuff, someone_else_too -[r2:LIKES]->stuff 
WITH b, someone_else_too, 
  CASE WHEN r1.frequency < r2.frequency 
    THEN r1.frequency 
    ELSE r2.frequency 
  END AS likeIndex 
RETURN likeIndex ,someone_else_too 
ORDER BY likeIndex DESC
```

Comment: Hi Wes. Unfortunately I am using 1.9. Any other thoughts or workarounds?

Comment: Btw result of your console is exactly what I was looking for. My other concern would be that even if I somehow upgraded my DB to 2.0, which is impossible with 7 million nodes, I am not quite sure if Neo4jClient supports case/when.

Comment: I don't think there's a good way without a non-aggregation min function or some way to do conditionals. You should be able to upgrade the store with 7 million nodes. Did you have trouble with it?

Comment: Not really sure how to upgrade from 1.9.2 to 2.0.X version. I thought it upgraded itself from 1.9.x to 1.9.y.  I also have not seen any comparison in speed of the two version so was holding off. Since it is non production, I can definitely try. I thought that one version of 2.0 version had breaking changes. Any pointers as how to upgrade ?

Comment: It's pretty easy, you just set the "allow_store_upgrade" flag in the neo4j.properties file (there's no going back, though, so you may want to make a backup), and then you start it up under 2.0. M03 is the one you want.

Comment: That sounds great. I will do that. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There a math way to get min value:

`(r1.frequency + r2.frequency - ABS(r1.frequency - r2.frequency))/2`

but it´s too litle heavy :(

Comment: This answer solved my use case pretty well. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could use apoc.coll.min:

```
  START b=node:node_auto_index(name='B') 
MATCH p = b-[r1:LIKES]->stuff, someone_else_too -[r2:LIKES]->stuff 
WITH b, someone_else_too, apoc.coll.min([r1.frequency, r2.frequency]) AS likeIndex 
RETURN likeIndex ,someone_else_too 
ORDER BY likeIndex DESC
```